# couln't match expected type with list sorting

Tags: haskell

we have to write a code with an higher-order function. It should be just one sentence long.
A given list will be checked, if it is sorted.
So far, I have this:

```
compare (a:xs) = foldl (\a b -> a < b ) True a xs || foldl (\a b -> a > b ) True
```

I alway get the error message: couln't match expected type bool witch actual type t0 Bool -> Bool. what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: the third argument of `foldl` must be a list, and `a` is not.

Hint 2: Using your fold,

```
foldl (\a b -> a < b) base [1,2,3]
= (((base < 1) < 2) < 3)
```

and something is wrong here: the result of `base < 1` is a boolean, and we can't compare that with `2` afterwards.

So, your function `\a b -> a < b` looks wrong in this context: it has the wrong type.

Comment: thanx! i did not see that. Well I guess it doen't work at all with a<b. i tried everything, most I got was the biggest element of the list.Or Is the idea with foldl utterly poppycock?

Comment: @letter The issue with folds is that they handle only one element at a time, which is troublesome in this case since you need two. There are ways to workaround that (e.g. building a function as the result of the fold, instead of a plain boolean), but they are cumbersome IMHO compared to plain recursion. If you really have to fold this, start by pairing adjacent elements as in `zip xs (tail xs)`, and then fold.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will try to give you some help of how you can do it.

First you should observe, that in order to check if a list is sorted you usually compare consecutive elements and check for example if they are ascending or not - note that you have to use *two consecutive* elements.

Now `foldl` and `foldr` let you only see one of them at a time - so you probably have to *remember* the *previous* element you saw somehow - and the only place to do this is to include it somehow in your state.

This can be done in various ways but I would recommend *tuples*.

So instead of the state being *is the list sorted so far*  I would but in a tuple *(is the list sorted so far, previous element)*.

Here is a simple template you have to fill with a few things:

```
isSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
isSorted (x:xs) = _A (foldl (\ (sorted,prev) cur -> (_B, _C)) (_D, _E) (_F))
```

if you try this this will not compile because you have to think about some **holes** (if you load it GHC(i) will help you with the types):

- `_E`,`_F` should have type `a` and `[a]` respectively, *hint* `_E` should be the first *previous* element you saw - as checking this predicate for empty lists is useless you can probably use `xs` and `x` somehow ;)
- `_D` should have type `Bool`
- `_C` should have type `a` and be your next *previous* element
- `_B` should have type `Bool` - this is where the **flesh** is - basically what you already tried
- `_A` should have type `(Bool, a) -> Bool` you'll figure it out.

I will give the solution in an hour or so to make this answer complete - but you should really try to do it by yourself

---

### solution

```
isSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
isSorted []     = True
isSorted (x:xs) = fst (foldl
                  (\ (sorted,prev) cur -> (sorted && prev <= cur, cur))
                  (True, x)
                  xs)
```

Comment: What do '$' and 'cur' stand for?

Comment: ok sorry (should not have used `$`) - it's really simple: `f $ x = f (x)` it will just let me be lazy and use fewer `(...)` - `cur` are the elements of your list that `foldl` will *show*  you (I choose the name to stand for *current element * - see: *previous*  and *current* ;))

Comment: Finally, I know what $ means. I saw it everywhere ;). And I am really sorry to ask,but what means sorted, '<=' and the syntax with (True,x)?

Comment: `sorted` just like `cur` is just a name of the anonymous function's argument for the `fold` - it's here used to keep track of if the list was sorted to this point - you did the very same ... `<=´ means `smaller or equal` ... well you used `<` so I kindof expected you to know this (how much about Haskell/Programming to you know anyways?), `(True,x)` is a tuple consisting of the value `True` and `x` the first saying: hey a list with one element is sorted and the second being the head of your list (as indicated by your own code: `(x:xs)`)